# A question involving Poisson processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, levy-processes

If $(N_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}_+}$ is a point process (or a Poisson process), what does it mean
$$ N_t - N_{t-} \in \{ 0, 1 \}? $$
Notation: $N_{t-} = \underset{u \rightarrow t^-}{lim} N_u$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may just mean that in an infinitesimal amount of time (say $dt$) you can only have at most one arrival. In other words, the probability of more than one arrival in a small interval $dt$ is negligible.